# How to enable php errors in wordpress htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have following .htaccess file code after installing wordpress:

```
#+PHPVersion
#="php73"
AddHandler x-httpd-php73 .php
#-PHPVersion

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now While I am trying to enable the display of php error by adding htaccess rule in between  and  by the following line:

```
php_value display_errors 1
```

The Website is showing:
[image]

As soon as I remove that line of code, the site is ok. As far I know, that line of code is necessary for showing/displaying any error of php code while visiting one page.

How to enable that in the above .htaccess code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According me, your code is write but you are getting error because you might be possible using php-fpm not mod_php

I am trying here give you the both solution

Below will be for php-fpm

**Step 1 : add .user.ini on root directory where you can find wp-config.php**

**Step 2 : add below code in the above file**

```
 display_errors = On
 display_startup_errors = On
 html_errors = 1
 error_reporting = -1
```

Now if you are using mod_php then add below code in .htacess

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_log /directory_path/errors.log
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
```

Adding `phpinfo();`  will help you to find that which (mod_php or php-fpm) has been under use.

Comment: It is showing php-fpm Active under cgi-fcgi in PHP INFO

Comment: User the first option of .usr.ini if that doesn’t work add php.ini on the same place and add same code

Comment: Although that doesn't work for me, but I have found to display error from my hosting panel dashboard. But I think your info is very useful and can help somebody else. So I have accepted your answer and upvoted. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress you can enable errors in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Comment: I have added but it is not showing the error. As for example, I have added a wrong url in require in php but it is not showing that the file is not exist.

Comment: Did you change the default false to true? I just tried it with your example and works for me: 
Warning: require(header.phpp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/....